# Unresolved external when using templates

Tags: c++, templates, unresolved-external

I'm mixing operator redefinition with template classes and reached to the following assigment:

```
j = end - begin;
```

in my main function, where variable types are as follows:

```
ptrdiff_t j;
util::BaseArrayIterator<int, 6> begin, end;
```

Begin and end have been initialized from a util::BaseArray:

```
util::BaseArray<int, 6> ba(SOME_PARAMETERS);
begin = ba.begin(); end = ba.end();
```

BaseArrayIterator is a self-implemented iterator type.

I get the error:

> ```
> TestProject.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> "int __cdecl util::operator-(class util::BaseArrayIterator<int,6>
> const &,class util::BaseArrayIterator<int,6> const &)" 
> (??Gutil@@YAHABV?$BaseArrayIterator@H$05@0@0@Z) referenced in
> function _main
> ```

due to the first code statement in the message (removing it fixes the problem).

I have included a header file with the following definitions and declarations:

```
namespace util {
template<typename T, int n>
typename BaseArrayIterator<T,n>::difference_type operator -
    (const BaseArrayIterator<T,n> &itL,
     const BaseArrayIterator<T,n> &itR);
...
template<typename T, int n>
typename BaseArrayIterator<T,n>::difference_type operator -(
    const BaseArrayIterator<T,n> &itL, 
    const BaseArrayIterator<T,n> &itR)
{   return -(itL.m_cnt - itR.m_cnt);
}
}
```

What causes the problem?
The compiler reports searching for a util::operator -, so he did find the declaration, but not the definition, although they are in the same file. And I see no signature mistake.

--- EDIT NOTE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Replacing

```
end-begin
```

with

```
util::operator-<int, 6>(end,begin)
```

solves the problem, but I don't want to explicitly specify the parameters each time. Concision is one of the main arguments in favor of overloading operator, so I'd like to use the classic short form.

--- EDIT NOTE 2 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

As Nicola Mussatti kindly indicated, [a solution]: [Unresolved external symbol with operator overloading and templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974319/unresolved-external-symbol-with-operator-overloading-and-templates) to the problem is here. Friend declaration should be moved inside the class.

So i did and I'm all smiles.
Now separating them back again issues an ambiguous overload issues, which is not the same error as previously.

Comment: try putting declarations in separate file from definitions. templates are very delicate things in c++. just try to change things until it works fine.

Comment: Separating declarations and definitions will just make things worse.

Comment: Could it be that the definition is outside the namespace? A `}` in the wrong place?

Comment: There was a missing closing } in my code fragment. I've added it.

Comment: I have vague recollections that there are issues related to the instantiation of operators that take class templates as arguments and are defined in a custom namespace, even if it's the same namespace where their argument types are defined. Could you try and move your operator definition inside your class template and declare it as friend?

Comment: The answer to [this question][1] appears to confirm my comment.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974319/unresolved-external-symbol-with-operator-overloading-and-templates

Comment: It worked indeed! Thanks! I didn't knew you can put friend declaration inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler are you using?

VS2010 is happy with this code:

```
namespace util
{
    template<typename T>
    class BaseArrayIterator
    {
    public:
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;

        int pos;
        T x;
    };

    template<typename T>
    typename BaseArrayIterator<T>::difference_type operator -
        (const BaseArrayIterator<T> &itL,
         const BaseArrayIterator<T> &itR);

    template<typename T>
    typename BaseArrayIterator<T>::difference_type operator -
        (const BaseArrayIterator<T> &itL,
         const BaseArrayIterator<T> &itR)
    {
        return itL.pos - itR.pos;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    util::BaseArrayIterator<int> a;
    util::BaseArrayIterator<int> b;

    ptrdiff_t dist = a - b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using VS2005. Probably the compiler is not cause.