# Unresolved external symbol with operator overloading and templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, linker-errors

In trying to compile this program:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    template<typename T>
    class Test {
    public:
        class Inner {
            int x;
            public:
                    Inner() : x(0) { }
            friend Inner& operator++(Inner& rhs);
        };

        Inner i;
    };
}

template<typename T>
typename MyNamespace::Test<T>::Inner& operator++(typename MyNamespace::Test<T>::Inner& rhs) {
    rhs = MyNamespace::Test<T>::Inner(rhs.x + 1);

    return rhs;
}

int main() {
    MyNamespace::Test<int> t;
    MyNamespace::Test<int>::Inner i = t.i;
    ++i;
}
```

I get the error

> unresolved external symbol "class MyNamespace::Test::Inner & __cdecl MyNamespace::operator++(class MyNamespace::Test::Inner &)" (??EMyNamespace@@YAAAVInner@?$Test@H@0@AAV120@@Z) referenced in function _main

Which is weird because that's the exact signature of the non-member friend function `operator++` that I defined. How do I fix this? And I do not have the option of including in as a member function because I need to change the object that the operand is referring to without using a copy constructor (because there is no copy constructor).

---

Update:

If I add `template<typename T>` above the `friend Inner&...`, I get the errors

```
could not deduce template argument for 'T' 1>         
main.cpp(21) : see declaration of 'operator
++' 
error C2783:
'MyNamespace::Test<T>::Inner &MyNamespace::operator++(MyNamespace::Test<T>::Inner &)' : could not deduce template
argument for 'T' with
[
              T=int
]          
main.cpp(13) : see declaration of
'MyNamespace::operator ++' 
main.cpp(30): error C2675: unary '++' : 'MyNamespace::Test<T>::Inner' does not define this operator or a
conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

with
[
              T=int
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it can't be a member function?  An instance member should work just fine:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    template<typename T>
    class Test
    {
    public:
        class Inner
        {
            int x;
        public:
            Inner& operator++( void ) { ++x; return *this; }
        };

        Inner i;
    };
}
```

This doesn't require a copy constructor.

Defining a friend should work too, as long as the definition is with the friend declaration:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    template<typename T>
    class Test
    {
    public:
        class Inner
        {
            int x;
        public:
            friend Inner& operator++( Inner& operand ) { ++operand.x; return operand; }
        };

        Inner i;
    };
}
```

The friend function will be placed at namespace scope, according to `[class.friend]`

Comment: Holy shiznits Benman, I never knew you could put the body of a friend function with the friend declaration itself! That's awesome, and thanks for your time. +1 and answer'd.

Comment: By the way, if you don't mind my asking, where did you learn that?

Comment: @Seth: I don't remember anymore where I first saw it.  But it's explicitly described in the C++ standard: "A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope." along with an overly simplistic example.